# why are null packets detected as virus by anti-virus programs

Tags: antivirus

why are null packets (bit stuffed) detected as virus by some anti-virus programs.

Comment: Please post the screenshots, as it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible reason I can think of is if the packets are seen as somehow distorting the hash of the completed stream. I know a lot of Anti-Virus programs store hashes of various viruses and as a way of disrupting that a lot of the viruses throw in null lines and No Op commands in order to distort that hash.

Comment: you Could be correct, thanks friend , i am still waiting for an alternative answers